# How to get the account id from the Quote Object

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have use onClick Javascript and I want to fetch the account id from the quote object.

```
var currentStatus = '{!Quote.Status}';
if( currentStatus  == 'Approved')
{
//create agreement to the account
How to get the account id here?

}
```

Comment: I presume you have tried "var accountId = '{!Quote.Account}';" which looks right according to the web Setup? But I notice that the Eclipse schema view does not list that field.

Comment: How to get the opportunity id from following onclickjava script : 
var opportunity = sforce.connection.query("Select Opportunityid From Quote where id = '{!Quote.Id}'");

Comment: Are you saying that the Quote fields you want to access have to be fetched on demand (onclick) rather than included in the page when it is rendered at the server? Why? (Example of extracing values from a sforce.connection.query result is here https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm)

Comment: I want to fetch the opportunity id from above the code. so how to get?

Comment: Are you using a standardController (Quote) or custom controller? if the first, you should be able to simply call `{!Quote.OpportunityId}` to get the Id (as oposed to the sforce.connection function). Here's a link to the fields for Quote too -- [link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm).

Comment: NO, am using javascript onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to play the SOQL to achieve this. pelase try the below method.

> Step 1: Get the opportunity Id from current Quote
>
> Step 2: find the Account id from that opportunity id.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Quote](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm) fields there is no **Account** field, only **OpportunityId**, however this does not work either, fails to **Save** the **Custom Button** script.

```
var opportunityId = '{!Quote.OpportunityId}';
alert(opportunityId);
```

If it did in theory something like **{!Quote.Opportunity.Account.Name}** ought to have worked, sadly i cannot get past **Quote.OpportunityId**, most other fields in the documentation work, but not this one!

It is supporting in SOQL, as i can query it....

```
System.debug([Select Opportunity.Account.Name From Quote][0].Opportunity.Account.Name);
```

> 21:57:34.072 (72477280)|USER_DEBUG|[1](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm)|DEBUG|Burlington Textiles Corp of America

Conclusion seems to be for some very strange reason this field is **not supported** in **Custom Button JavaScript** scripts. Its not even present in the drop down either...

[image]

Bizzarly as Keith C points out it is listed under the **Setup Fields** page for the object.

[image]

**Possible Alternative**

It is however accessible from a **Visualforce page**, you can then link to a **Custom Button**, the downside with this approach is it presents another page for the user to then press the button...

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote">
    <script>
    function doSomething()
    {
        var accountName = '{!Quote.Opportunity.Account.Name}';
        alert(accountName);
    }
    </script>
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Quote" subtitle="{!Quote.Name}"/>
    <apex:form>
        <input type="button" value="Do Something" onclick="doSomething()" class="btn"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: Does the same button work on a salesforce1 app? Just asking since I do not have much experience with Salesforce1. I backed off and dropped out as soon as I saw Salesforce1 app tag

Comment: Actually, i have not spotted that! I've not had chance to test it in Salesforce1 yet, i should do, the Visualforce page will need the mobile enabled checkbox selected

Comment: Hi I am using onclick java script and if i put '{!Quote.OpportunityId}'; I got this error "Field Quote.OpportunityId does not exist. Check spelling."

Comment: Yes, that was my finding above in my answer... 'however this does not work either, fails to Save the Custom Button script'. Its strange, but i cannot get it to work other than using a Visualforce page.